# Creating an apt repository on GitHub

Tags: github, repository, debian, apt

Can I create an apt repository from my GitHub repository?

I found [How To Setup A Debian Repository](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository) but it is too complex to understand.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that it would be possible, but it not very practical.  Git and GitHub are designed for storing source code, while an apt repository is setup to serve built packages. As far as git would be concerned, even a Debian source package would not be source code.  But, since GitHub pages allow serving of largely arbitrary content via http, it should be possible to serve an apt repository in that way.

The page to which you referred doesn't seem at all complex to me, it's just a list of tools which can be used to manage an apt repository. The part listing [Archive Generation Tools](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToSetupADebianRepository#APT_Archive_Generation_Tools) should be especially helpful. In the past I've used `mini-dinstall` to manage my own package archive, you'd probably want use either that or `reprepro`; the other tools are probably either trying to do too much (providing the capability to manage an entire distribution repository) or too little.

Comment: I have a source code repo on github and for quick distriobution I have there an directory containing packages (now rpms but I want to create debs). I must study this repo things and than I figure out something :) so thanks